# I can write on a smb share from android only if I'm connected with wifi

Tags: android, connection, wifi, samba, smb

It's a weird problem.
I have different android devices and I need to write txt files and zipped pdf files on a smb share.
Everything works fine but one day 4 devices out of about 40 aren't able to write on it using a mobile data connection.
Nothing changed or at least I think.
The model of the tablets are: TAB Samsung A8 SMX205 and TAB Samsung A7 SMT505.

If I take the sim card of a tablet that can't write anymore and I put it in another tablet that continued to work normally, I will write files without problems. So the sim card is not the problem.
If I take  a sim card from a tablet that works normally and put it in a tablet that can't write I will not able to write again.

With wifi connection everything works fine.

The problem appeared the same day on that 4 devices.
The tablets are all updated.

I can't explain it.

Comment: Your app on an Android device can write on a Windows share using a sim-card? How will that go?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve SMB connectivity problems is to capture network traffic with let's say Wireshark and analyze for errors.